# replace user login / passward div with a div that display username and logout button

Tags: php, html, authentication, replace, logout

```
<div class="login">
<form name="loginform" action="index.php" method="post">
<h5>Username<input type="text" name="login_username" value='<?php $_POST[login_username]?>' size="15"/>    
<br/>
Password 
<input type="password" name="login_password" value='<?php $_POST[login_password]?>' size="15"/>      
<br />
<center><input type="submit" name="login" value="sign in" />                                                
 <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code than just this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using sessions, you would just do a check on the page:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedin']===true){?>
<div>
    <div>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></div>
    <div><a href="logout.php">Logout</div>
</div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="login">
    <form name="loginform" action="index.php" method="post">
    <h5>Username<input type="text" name="login_username" value='<?php $_POST[login_username]?>' size="15"/>    
    <br/>
    Password 
    <input type="password" name="login_password" value='<?php $_POST[login_password]?>' size="15"/>      
    <br />
    <center><input type="submit" name="login" value="sign in" />                                                
    <br />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am shooting in the dark because I have no idea what is going on server side, but this is the general idea.